# magento 2.3.1 inventory:reservation missing commands

Tags: magento2, php, php-7

I have inventory_reservation inconsistencies that I need to clean up on M2 2.3.1 so following this wiki guide https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/CLI-Reference but when running it I get error

'there are no commands defined in the inventory:reservation namespace".

Comment: ? anyone have an idea?

Comment: set permission to your root and others.

Comment: ran command as root

Comment: verify with php bin/magento

Comment: still no joy getting this to work

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with that too. So, after some research, here are my findings:

There's no CLI module installed, so you need to install it or upgrade MSI to latest version. For Magento 2.3.1 in particular, use: `composer require "magento/inventory-composer-metapackage": "1.1.3 as 1.1.1"`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Magento_InventoryReservationCli` module is enabled:

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_InventoryReservationCli
```